# Get the latest rows from a 'with CTE' query that returns duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have an existing query that uses the 'with CTE' function. This query returns my desired results, however, the query also returns duplicate values but with different update dates. To give you an example, the query returns results like this:

```
NAME     MACHINE   SUPERVISOR    LAST_UPDATE
NAME_1   T_001     SUP_1         2015-10-14 09:55:26.637
NAME_2   T_002     SUP_2         2015-10-14 09:54:07.087
NAME_2   T_002     SUP_3         2015-10-14 10:02:31.663 
NAME_3   T_003     SUP_4         2015-10-14 09:53:28.253 
NAME_4   T_005     SUP_4         2015-10-14 09:55:47.293
NAME_3   T_003     SUP_3         2015-10-14 09:59:00.000
NAME_3   T_003     SUP_3         2015-10-12 08:19:00.000
```

I want to only select the rows with same name and machine that has latest update dates. The desired result should be:

```
NAME     MACHINE   SUPERVISOR    LAST_UPDATE
NAME_1   T_001     SUP_1         2015-10-14 09:55:26.637
NAME_2   T_002     SUP_3         2015-10-14 10:02:31.663 
NAME_4   T_005     SUP_4         2015-10-14 09:55:47.293
NAME_3   T_003     SUP_3         2015-10-14 09:59:00.000
NAME_3   T_003     SUP_3         2015-10-12 08:19:00.000
```

**Take note that the selecting of latest rows applies on a daily basis. Look at NAME_3. It removes the other row on the same day, but not the row that is updated on a different day.**

Please keep in mind that there is an existing query and what I hoping for is to just integrate another query that will get the desired results above. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `order by` `hour`, `minute` and `seconds` as well if you need one record per day if there are more than 1 entries for a given day.

```
select name, machine, supervisor, last_update
from (select *,
      row_number() over (partition by name, course, cast(last_update as date)
                         order by last_update desc,
                         datepart(hh,last_update),            
                         datepart(minute,last_update), 
                         datepart(second,last_update)) as rn
     from tablename
     ) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: it seems that `last_update` is the only field you need to order by because it already contains the time part?

Comment: Hmm.. I don't understand why do you need to part hour, minute and second as well? Isn't parting year, month and day would suffice?

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplicated columns, you can use

`ROW_NUMBER()`: `PARTITION BY duplicated columns` then remove `rownum > 1`.

`ROW_NUMBER()` and `RANK()`: `PARTITION BY duplicated columns` then remove rows which have `rownum <> rank`

You code like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT NAME, MACHINE, SUPERVISOR, LAST_UPDATE
   FROM ...
   WHERE ...
)
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME, MACHINE, CONVERT(DATE, LAST_UPDATE)
                        ORDER BY LAS_UPDATE DESC) AS rownum
   FROM CTE
)
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Comment: Why did you add date in PARTITION BY?? It's only needed in order by section. If you use it like you used - every different date will be the first (rownum = 1).

Comment: Look question: **Take note that the selecting of latest rows applies on a daily basis. Look at NAME_3. It removes the other row on the same day, but not the row that is updated on a different day.**

Comment: О_о Thanks! Didn't notice it.